# Retrieving/returning gamestate from erlang's message passing construct

Tags: erlang

I was looking at some games made using erlang and I found one simple tic-tac-toe game [here](https://github.com/bekkopen/erlang-tictactoe). I understood this game but I had a simple question that the person has used `io:format()` to show gamestate. So when I make a move like

```
gameclient:make_move(Player1, ChallengedPlayer, Message),
```

all I get in return is

```
{make_move,"player1",a3}
```

But I wanted to know that how can I retrieve the current gamestate on calling the function `make_move/3`.

I don't think using mnesia is a good option here.

Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve/return the gamestate rather than just printing it using io:format.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ETS table for example

1. **create table at startup:**

   ```
   ets:new(tik_tak_tab, [public, {read_concurrency, true}, ordered_set,named_table]).
   ```
2. **store data into the table:**

   ```
   loop(Name) ->
     receive
       { msg, Message } ->
           ets:insert(tik_tak_tab, {state, Message}),
           loop(Name)  
     end.
   ```
3. **Make new function to retreive the state:**

   ```
   some_func() ->
     case ets:lookup(tik_tak_tab, state) of
       [{state, Message}] -> Message;
       _ -> error
     end.
   ```

_. **There is also cheap way to use records**

You may check detailed [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html)

Comment: well sorry for the late reply but this will print the game state called. That's okay but what I wanted was to get the value of **NewGameState** into a variable on each call to the make_move function. What I am actually doing is that I am running this game on ejabberd server and what I did was to store the NewGameState inside the mnesia table on each call and then I read it then in the very next line I read the **NewGameState** from the mnesia table but I found it to be empty, but when I wrote a timer:sleep(200) between the two line I found the mnesia table was filled with the game state.